# Dynamic Count of Boolean Operations in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, boolean

I want to be able to change the number of boolean operations based on an input integer. 
Is this possible?

Ex:

- Input 2: `a = df[0] & df[1]`
- Input 3: `a = df[0] & df[1] & df[2]`

Comment: Can't u do this in a for loop and what id df ? will it be an array of size equal to ur input number and u are trying to do & of all the elements ?

Comment: This question is lacking context. You have a Pandas DataFrame? And you want to check if the first `n` elements of some underlying column are all true?

Comment: It should be noted that `&` is not a boolean operator, but a bitwise operator.  If you want to do this with boolean operators, you can use the `all` function.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Variable named `df` suggests it is likely OP is using Pandas, where `&` is redefined to logical-and.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular example:

```
n = <Desired number>

a = df[0]

for i in range(1, n):
    a &= df[i]
```